# Weights and Scale Problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

a.) What is the minimum number of integer weights to balance a scale with bags of rocks from weights 1 to n.

b.) What is the minimum number of weights to balance a scale of weights on one side and on the second side bags of rocks with weights as well as weights on one side from 1 to n integer weights.

-I really need a clear explanation please
- A few attempts I had were 1 weights but that wasnt right and then I started to get triangle numbers but I am lost on what I am doing.

Comment: Clearly for $n=1$ the answer is you need a weight of $1$.  Try by hand for weights up to $10$ or so.  You should be able to see a pattern.  Triangle numbers are not correct.  If you have to put weights on one side only you need a $2$ for the case $n=2$.  Then you don't need a $3$ because you can do $1+2$

Comment: i forgot to mention integer weight combinations and what about the second part?

Answer (score 0):

a.  Let k be the largest integer with $2^k$ <= n.
k + 1 weights are needed, each being a power of 2.

b.  I'll pass trying to figure it out.